# NSTableview with arraycontroller and binding!

Tags: cocoa-bindings

can any one help me out in NStableView with arraycontroller and binding?
what are the procedure to start with.

or share any link having full tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

basic: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000080.php

coredata: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php

different angle: http://uselessthingies.wordpress.com/2008/05/18/nsarraycontrollers-an-example/

list of cocoa binding tips http://homepage.mac.com/mmalc/CocoaExamples/controllers.html (don't underestimate them based on their publication date...)